# Using aspnet range validator on html input control

Tags: c#, rangevalidator

I am building a small web application in c#.
I am using the range validator and I want to bind it to an html control that has the runat="server" attribute to it.

From some reason it won't bind and won't perform any check for the content of the control. Does any of you have an idea what to do?

Comment: can you please provide part of your code

Comment: Why are you not using an ASP.NET TextBox control? Any particular reason? I don't think the ASP.NET validator controls work with HtmlControls.

Comment: Without any additional info or some code it is hard to tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this link from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972961.aspx) it should work

```
    <td>
       <asp:RangeValidator id="id" runat="server" ErrorMessage="not 2"
       ControlToValidate="txtbx_value" MaximumValue="3" MinimumValue="1" 
       Type="Integer"> </asp:RangeValidator>
    </td>
    <td>User ID:</td>
    <td><input type=text runat=server id=txtbx_value></td>
```